# Check multiple variables against file

Tags: php, duplicates

I'm trying to search a text document for variables entered into a form and check whether there are duplicates or not. The program would be searching for several variables (First name, last name, and email). I am able to search for a single variable and have the program return that there is already an entry, but as soon as I add in a second variable I run into all sorts of trouble. Current code is only searching for first and last name. I'll add the third variable after I can successfully locate the two current ones. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $fname = stripslashes($_POST['firstname']);
                $lname = stripslashes($_POST['lastname'] . PHP_EOL);
                $existingnames = array();
                $namefile = fopen("test_dupes.txt", "a+");


                if(file_exists("test_dupes.txt")){
                    $existingnames = file("test_dupes.txt");

                    if(in_array($fname, $existingnames)){

                        if(in_array($lname, $existingnames)){
                            echo "<p>The name is already in the file!<br>";
                            echo "Please enter another name.</p>";
                        }

                    } else {
                        fwrite($namefile, "$fname" . " ");
                        fwrite($namefile, "$lname");
                        fclose($namefile);
                        echo "Your name has been successfully added to the list.";
                    }

                } else {

                    if($namefile === false) {
                    echo "There was an error saving your name to the file.";

                    } else{
                        fwrite($namefile, "$fname" . " ");
                        fwrite($namefile, "$lname");
                        fclose($namefile);
                        echo "Your name has been successfully to the list.";
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>

        <form action="test_dupes.html">
            <input type="submit" value="Return to Name Entry" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall, I think this seems like a better job for a database, but I think I can explain the current problem you are having with it.

If you have a file that contains a list of full names like this:

```
John Moran
Someone Else
Another Name
...
```

Then when you read them into an array using `file()` You will end up with an array containing full names like this:

```
array("John Moran\n", "Someone Else\n", "Another Name\n", etc.);
```

When you use `in_array($fname, $existingnames)` to try to find an existing first name, it will try to match `$fname` with a value in the array, but since the array contains full names, nothing will match. If you want to just use `in_array` to check the name, you need to check it with first and last name together (I think this is probably why it was working when you just had one variable.) With two variables, you can just put them back together, like this:

```
in_array("fname $lname", $existingnames)
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you very much. I was assuming that when $fname was added to the file that it would retain itself as $fname instead of combining with $lname.